# listen to events from https ifram

Tags: javascript, iframe

we have a login iframe that can be load from any page in the site.

the iframe raise an event when it close, and the parent page listen to it and remove the iframe when it fire.

now we are trying to use https calls for the login and we load the iframe using https url.

to enable the event listening we set the `document.domain` of both the page and the iframe to the same domain (because they have different subdomain), and its work fine if both use the same protocol, but it can be done with 2 different protocols (http and https).

Is there any solution to the problem?

Comment: You can do it with [PostMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Comment: Thanks, its look like its the solution. i'll try it